# FOR loop does not work due to spaces in filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a batch file I have this code for copying files:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B *.png,*.jpg,*.pneg,*.jpeg') DO (
    XCOPY /H /S /Y /EXCLUDE:%EXFdestination%\EXF.txt %%~f "%destination%\" 
)
```

Problem is it doesn't copy files with spaces in the filenames like `D:\Exemple Directory\file.jpg`, it only copies files that have filenames like `D:\ExampleDirectory\file.jpg`

I tried instead of `tokens=*` with `delims=` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough: use `"%%~f"` instead of `%%~f`

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass the for loop and use Robocopy.

Here is an example:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\Source" "C:\Destination" *.png *.jpg *.pneg *.jpeg /s
```

There are also exclude options **/XF** and **/XD**, but we have not seen the content of your exclude file **EXF.txt**.